Optimizing Redis Key Management for Multi-Company Applications
I am setting up Redis for my application, which will serve hundreds of companies. I am considering a key structure like this:
companyname1:xxx:yyy:zzz
companyname1:yyy
companyname1:qqq:zz:xxx:ppp
companyname1:tttt:zz:qqq
companyName1:iiii:rrrr
companyName1:ppp:ddd:xxx
[... thousands more]

Each company would follow a similar pattern. I need to be able to remove all keys that contain "xxx" at any position, but only for companyname1.
How can I organize it so that Redis does not have to search through the entire database? Is there a way to group keys for each company and then operate only on that specific group?
I initially did something like this, but I do not know if it has the right to work, and most importantly, if it is efficient. I'm using StackExchange.
var keysToDelete = new List<RedisKey>();
var cursor = 0L;
var pageSize = 100; 

// pattern = "companyName1::xxx:";
do
{
    var redisResult = await _database.ExecuteAsync("SCAN", cursor.ToString(), "MATCH", pattern, "COUNT", pageSize).ConfigureAwait(false);
    var result = (RedisResult[])redisResult;

    cursor = Convert.ToInt64((string)result[0]);
    keysToDelete.AddRange((RedisKey[])result[1]);
}
while (cursor != 0);

I would appreciate any guidance.
Remove keys for single companay, pattern to remove can be anywhere in the key

Firstly: the SCAN API is implemented in SE.Redis on the IServer interface, see https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/KeysScan.
However, there doesbnot exist an efficient way to do this that uses redis "string" keys; by necessity you will have to walk the entire keyspace if using the approach you suggest.
If you were searching on a "left" substring, a solution using the redis "hash" type might have been appropriate, but for "anywhere in the key": not so much.
If you're not using "cluster", it might help to partition each client into a separate database (see SELECT in redis terms, or see https://redis.io/glossary/databases/; this is a parameter to GetDatabase() in SE.Redis). You'll still have to walk the keyspace, but only for a single client - not all clients.

Thank you for reply. What if I want to use a Redis cluster because a single Redis instance might be overloaded with hundreds of clients, and I want to scale it? I'm currently using Redis standalone, am I somehow limited with databases?

@TomaszCioch the "database" feature is only available on standalone, not on cluster; so: measure both based on realistic data load (allowing for future growth), and make your choices from there, I guess\
